# Not able to use PrintDocument in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, printing

I am running an asp.net application's app pool under my ID which has access to Printer. Below is my code which uses `DrawString` to print a string generated from code.

```
 PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
 pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = @"\\aPrint\0007-BOND";
 pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
 pd.Print();
```

and `pd_PrintPage` is defined below

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12);
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(props, f, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);
            ev.HasMorePages = false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Above code works well in my Visual Studio whereas giving error when deployed on IIS. I believe my printer settings and permissions are good as i can print other documents using 'COM' library functions like `Word`, `Excel` etc

What's wrong in my shared code? Please suggest

Comment: Can the server iis is installed on access the printer?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, it can

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-most-common-technologies-not-supported-by-microsoft-8675c409bde2 System.Drawing and printing related classes are not supported in web apps.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks So much. Understood the reason why application was executing forever despite not printing after reading the blog..What should be the alternate in this case then?

Comment: Ideally you set up a WinForms app and use inter-process communication to pass printing requests to it. Or you might check if there is a third party library that can work in web apps.